# Java default Integer value is int

Tags: java, data-types, type-casting, byte

My code looks like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class StudentGrades {

public static void main(String[] argv)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    byte q1 = keyboard.nextByte() * 10;
}
}
```

It gives me an error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte.`

Why would Java store a literal operand that is small enough to fit in a byte, into an int type? Do literals get stored in variables/registers before the ALU performs arithmetic operations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is the line `byte q1 = keyboard.nextByte() * 10;`. There are no arithmetic operations on `byte` or `short`. The value of `keyboard.nextByte()` is casted up to an `int` prior to multiplication with 10, which is also an `int`. The result of the multiplication is an `int`, which can not be stored into `q1` if it's defined as a `byte`.

Possible solutions would be to cast the result of the multiplication to a byte using `(byte) (keyboard.nextByte() * 10)` or by changing the type of `q1` to `int`.

Unfortunately, I'm not finding a reference to this in the tutorials. However, you can find an explanation in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). Sections [5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) and [15.18.2 Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) define this behavior.

Comment: +1: Good answer and direct references to the JLS are always win.

Comment: For anyone interested: number literals are integers in .NET too.

Comment: @Thomas Owens What do you mean "There are no arithmetic operations on byte or short? Do you mean there isn't any in my expression, or Java doesn't allow it, and must cast it up as an int, which allows arithmetic operations? Is this why keyboard.nextByte() casts up to int?

Comment: @ChrisOkyen The operations `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, and I believe `%` are not defined for type `byte` or `short`. Variables of type `byte` or `short` are casted to `int` if they are used with one of these operations. It's all explained in the links I provided to the Java Language Specification.